# How to get current position of file

Tags: file, go

I'm reading a file part by part and want to print the File Position (Byte Position). Example code snippet:

```
inFile *os.File
inFile, err := os.Open(myfile)
size := make([]byte, some_size)
content_size, err := inFile.Read(size)
```

Now this is done in a loop with various buffer sizes. So do I have to maintain a variable where I'll add up the content size obtained as return data from Read?

Instead, can I get the position (Bytes) of the file pointer after all the Read operations are done? How can I get this current position of the file?

Comment: `Read` returns how many bytes have been read and thats your position. Could you state your problem clearer?

Comment: You should track the position by incrementing the `content_size` variable. Alternatively you could use `Seek(0, 1)` to get the current offset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [File.Seek](https://godoc.org/os#File.Seek) returns the resulting offset in the file. To get the current offset, seek zero bytes from the current position:

```
 offset, err := f.Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent)
```